# Display a Qr code ( an image formula field) in a VisualForce page

Tags: visualforce, formula-field, qr-code

I have a requirement where I want to display a Qr code related to a record in a visualforce page in order to generate a PDF . I have managed to generate the pdf , howver , The Qr code is not displayed ....I have tried these 3 different ways for displaying a QR code in my visualforce page ( the QR code is generated by an image formula field).
[image: Code used]

[image: Apex code for the third Method]

but here is what is displayed whatever what I do :

[image: What I got]

Comment: What's the data type for `QR_Code__c`? How is the QR Code stored?

Comment: Also, P.S., a query never returns a `null` list. It might be empty, but not null.

Comment: @sfdcfox I see , thanks for the info .... The DataType for QR_Code__c is : Formula (Text)

Comment: @sfdcfox  Here is the formula I used to generate the QR code: IMAGE('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl='+Name,'test')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have barcodes or QR codes show up on VFpages that are rendered as PDFs, just add a Remote Site Setting for the domain the image is being generated from in your formula field (e.g., https://chart.googleapis.com or https://www.barcodesinc.com).  This will allow the image to be included in the PDF being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and solved based on this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XatcQAC

HTML: `<apex:image value="{!qrCodeUrl}"/>`

Apex ControllerExtension:

```
public without sharing class DF_OrderPDFController {

    public String qrCodeUrl{get;set;} 
    
    public DF_OrderPDFController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        dfOrder = (DF_Order__c)stdController.getRecord();     
        qrCodeUrl = [SELECT DF_QR_CodeLink__c FROM DF_Order__c WHERE Id = :dfOrder.Id LIMIT 1].DF_QR_CodeLink__c;

    }
}
```

The DF_Order__c field contains the url, it is a text formula field: "https://chart.googleapis.com/..."